# Downside of having string properties in service contracts that can contain a full json model

Tags: json, service, domain-driven-design, modeling

We are working with a DDD framework in our company. We are changing a lot of core things in our API because we are still growing and we are still in our enfant phase when designing a good API.
The problem is that there are alot of flows already in the same api. Which are not compatible with eachother.

We have an order service and a product service.
Normally  when the product model radically changes, we have a major impact in the order model.
Now im here listing all kind of red flags which should never happen but I simply dont have control over how it needs to be done. That is pretty much management pushing for a fast solution. And leading to bad shortcuts...

The way is has been decided to overcome that Order needs to adapt constantly. They made a property in the orderline called productConfiguration. This is in the contract of the service and is direcrtly translated as is in the DB tables. This contains the product model that can change. In json format.

For me its very clear that this is very dangerous to do this. Because i nthe end you need to change this json into an actual object. So  you just move the restrictions from the service contract to code logic. Which makes it worse cause it will only cause an issue at run time...

Are there other major things I just know about, so I can bring it to the table to avoid this way of working...

Answer (score 0):

Using strings that are directly converted into DB tables is not just in your opinion a bad design. It's an opinion shared by a lot of us.

What do you do when an object changes? For example, the new one requires an attribute that the old one didn't had. How do you manage this situation? I suppose that you've to change everything, including the objects stored before. Or build a kind of transformation layer where you translate objects from the old to the new design. A lot of extra work.

Anyway, given that the two domains are separated, what are the information that change so much and require such a design? I mean, for most of the things you could know at the beginning what do you need for your part of the domain. For the rest, I would prefer to have a kind of service that given an Id gives you the information from the other domain. You can change this service (here could be also json obj, if nothing than just showing is required) and adapt to your/their needs. But, it's just a solution that comes from my limited knowledge of your processes.

Other ways are also possible, as long as you can always understand which version of the design are you using.